# i can handle the gigabit ethernet?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, ethernet

I ran the `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` command and I got:

`/dev/sda`: Timing cached reads:   `18832 MB in  2.00 seconds = 9424.15
MB/sec`

Timing buffered disk reads: `544 MB in  3.01 seconds = 180.77
MB/sec`

And with the `ethtool eth0` command:

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
```

These configurations can handle the Gigabit Ethernet if I buy it? Can I get the maximum speed? Or I have to buy a SSD?

Answer (score 2):

```
1GBit = 1000MBit = 1000 (MBit / 8Bit) * Byte = 125MByte
```

Any reasonably 3,5" 7200RPM HDD should be able to handle that.
At least when performing sequential writes. The performance will be worse with random writes.

I don't think this is an issue though. If you're writing a lot of small files over the network, performance is typically bottle-necked by the network transfer protocol. From my own experience I can tell, that SMB performs terribly when it comes to a large number of files.

Using SSDs in a pure storage setting (e.g a NAS) is a waste of money.

However, in addition to much faster read/write rates, their strength is access time. In a server setting with many concurrent read/write request, like a web- or mail-server, an SSD can make quite the difference.

Since you already own the HDD, you might want to try and make do with it first. If the performance is not satisfying you can still buy a suitable SSD and replace the hard-drive.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer should be able to handle Gigabit Ethernet just fine regardless for the HDD.  It's what's a bottleneck is the issue.  If you want to be able to write to the HDD over the network at 1 gigabit per second, then that's going to require a hard drive that can *write* at 1000 megabits/sec, or 250MB/sec.

You can use Gigabit LAN with a slower HDD, you just can't write to that HDD over the network at 1Gbps.  You will benefit from having Gigabit LAN in other ways, so go for it anyways.

Comment: Ah ok!  I'll start my watch.

Comment: @Lurrdock Sorry Daniel, but there is a not so inconsequential error in your calculation: 1Gbit = 125MByte

Comment: Yeah, that ^.  I've been multitasking too much.